# Error installing `CLHEP` : make: *** [install] Error 1

Tags: software-installation, make

I am trying to install CLHEP [[clhep.2.3.2.2.tgz] .

make and  make test working but for "make install", im getting following error....

```
/home/ainnie/clhep-build/include/CLHEP/GenericFunctions/X.hh
-- Up-to-date: /home/clhep-build/bin/Geometry-config
-- Up-to-date: /home/clhep-build/include/CLHEP/Geometry/BasicVector3D.h
-- Up-to-date: /home/clhep-build/include/CLHEP/Geometry/Normal3D.h
-- Up-to-date: /home/clhep-build/include/CLHEP/Geometry/Plane3D.h
-- Up-to-date: /home/clhep-build/include/CLHEP/Geometry/Point3D.h
-- Up-to-date: /home/clhep-build/include/CLHEP/Geometry/Transform3D.h
-- Up-to-date: /home/clhep-build/include/CLHEP/Geometry/Transform3D.icc
-- Up-to-date: /home/clhep-build/include/CLHEP/Geometry/Vector3D.h
CMake Error at Geometry/src/cmake_install.cmake:42 (file):
  file INSTALL cannot find
  "/home/ainnie/clhep-build/lib/libCLHEP-Geometry-2.3.2.2.so".
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  Geometry/cmake_install.cmake:42 (include)
  cmake_install.cmake:196 (include)



Makefile:105: recipe for target 'install' failed
make: *** [install] Error 1
```

Please help me to solve this error. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
cd ~/CLHEP-build
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=~/CLHEP ~/CLHEP-source/2.3.1.0/CLHEP
make
make test
make install
PATH="$PATH":~/CLHEP/bin
```